# Protecting files/folders making them accessible only to certain users, for a limited period of time

Tags: file, server

Is there a way where i can protect the access to certain files in a folder?
What i need to achieve is, user send his email, it receives a temporary password that lasts for 30 min, he then uses that password to access some files. To access those files again he needs to send another email as the password changes.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use node
I suggest you use jwt to verify the user it's meant for cases like this

Comment: Ok, i want also to prevent the file from being directly accessible from the browser, thats where i struggle, can i make some configuration that allows it to be accessible only from node?

Comment: do i just need to put it a folder up? is it ok?

Comment: It also works for that too
something like this
Const app=require('express')()
app.get('/path-to-file',authfunc,{
res.send(file)
}

Comment: ok thanks ill try